# Use Java records with JSON-B + Jax-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, jsonb-api

My project uses JSON-B with JAX-RS. The framework I am using is Quarkus and use Java 11. I tried to upgrade to Java 16 and use Java Records. It seems that JSON-B and Records does not work nicely.

I have tried @JsonbCreator. But this annotation only works with a single constructor.

I have also tried to use the Apache Johnzon as shown here (https://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/java_14_java_record_json). But Quarkus Resteasy does not have a Johnzon binding.

Is there a solution that would allow me to switch to Java Records?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quarkus uses [Eclipse Yasson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson) as its JSON-B implementation and currently Yasson does not support Records.
However that will likely change soon, see [this](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/495) issue.

If you are willing to move away from JSON-B, you can use Jackson with Quarkus and have Records support as Jackson supports them since version `2.12`

Comment: I am using Quarkus 2.13.3, which does have a Jackson which is recent enough, but it fails to work! Anyone know why?

Comment: As of Mar 2024, Java Records (baseline Java 14 or 17 for LTS) are partially supported by e.g. Yasson, but not officially supported by JSON-B spec as it maintains backward compatibility with Java 11 where records do not exist. Here is a tracking issue: https://github.com/jakartaee/jsonb-api/issues/278